# In 2D animation, the character goes into idle mode when a key is pressed in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, topdown

Instead of animating a character in an inactive(Idle) state.

[The B key is pressed here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leO4R.png).

[After a while the animation works again:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNKgm.png).

[Exit time is disabled for transitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGlOo.png).

Player Controller file code:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Animator animator;
    Vector2 movement;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);   
    }
}
```

Horizontal and Vertical parameters:
[Animator Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPgvo.png)
[Animator Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkRcM.png)

Here are the transitions between the idle state and the running state (Movement):
[Animator Transition Idle -> Movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYjcG.png)
[Animator Transition Movement-> Idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyCpz.png)

After the speed parameter becomes greater than 0.01, the character goes into the running state(Movement), if less than 0.01, back to the idle state.

Comment: ` tried enabling exit time, but it doesn't affect` affect *what*?

Comment: I thought it would affect the animation transitions, but animation also works incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Please try to rephrase it. I don't see anything in code that changes state on button press. Where are you using the "Horizontal" and "Vertical" parameters?

May be this [Getting started with Unity Animation](https://vionixstudio.com/2023/01/09/unity-animation/) guide will help you.

Comment: I added screenshots where the vertical and horizontal parameters are used. When I press and hold the button, there should be a transition from the idle state to the running animation. But sometimes, instead, the character moves, but remains in the idle state (as in the screenshot "The B key is pressed here:"). That is, the running animation does not work, but the character moves.

 Thank you for your attention to my question.

Comment: I don't see a code or parameter for transition on button press from Idle to movement.

Comment: I added information above to clarify how the transition occurs in the animator. It all depends on the speed parameter.

Comment: The condition for Idle to movement is set to Speed less than 0.01. It should be greater than 0.01

Comment: Oh...Most likely this was the problem, but I just decided to write all the animation transitions in the code.
Thank you for your attention to my problem, I will be more attentive next time.